# Is there any issues in changing extension of .html to .aspx?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Is there any issues in changing extension of .html to .aspx. The SharePoint platform in our company seems to accept only aspx file. I changed one page and seems to be working fine. I have not worked with asp before, so would like know if it would cause any issues in future.

Comment: aspx accepts HTML markup so... i guess no

Comment: ASPX files also contains HTML markup & JS, then renaming it should working fine if you have not using server-side code-behind and dynamically generated elements.

Answer (score 1):

### Totally Fine - No Issues

There is no problem at all. All it means is that the browser and server will recognise that it can contain ASPX code.

You will have issues trying to open it in a browser locally if you have no server set up, but other than that, it's the same.

It's also the same if you rename an HTML page to PHP. It's just to help the server/browser understand what's inside, which can also be HTML.

Comment: What does it mean by opening it in a browser locally? We have stored the files in SharePoint library which we kinda use as a server at the moment.

Comment: An HTML web page doesn't require a server to run. It will run anywhere. Whereas an ASPX page is asking for a server to process it. So if you try and open it locally on your home computer and you don't have a server running, it won't render. It will just display the code as if you have opened it in an editor.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: My pleasure Vishal!

Answer (score 0):

What is the task at hand for which you need to change html extension to aspx.

Aspx means active server pages and html is only a part of these pages. These pages contain a lot more information which is required by SharePoint for their processing

Html pages are simple html pages containing dom elements... I have never seen a sharepoint link ending at an **html** file e.g http://sharepointsite.com/index.html

[Read more: here](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-asp-and-html)

Comment: SharePoint only?!!!

Comment: @Ashraf Aspx is whole lot different than simple html. And renaming aspx to html uploading it to sharepoint and trying to route something to it won't work!

Comment: Bro its not only `sharepoint` , aspx is basically an `ASP.NET` page .

Comment: @Ashraf Questioner has mentioned sharepoint that why i gave my answer in that perspective

Comment: We have created a website in html and was stored in the site assets in SharePoint library in SharePoint 2013. We could launch the site by going to the link in the site assets. Recently, SharePoint upgraded to office 365 and we no longer can launch the site directly from the library unless we change to aspx.

Comment: @VishalRaju If your html pages are in _site assets_  or anyother document library then yes they will not open/run because this will require authentication because _site assets_ is not for public view... You may transfer the html file to folder situation at root like **_catalogue** or create a new folder for example. This can be done using SP Designer... and so any html file from these folders will open.

Comment: @VishalRaju If you are able to run html files sitting in _site assets_ once you change .html to .aspx then all's good!! :) even though is very surprising

Comment: @akg1421 That's what I thought. When I changed to .aspx, it is opening fine. I wanted to know if there would be any issues but I guess there isn't as long as it is a static website.

Answer (score 0):

**In terms of execution :** You'll be required to host the files under IIS in order to run your application .

**In terms of performance:** For sure , when you put `.aspx` , you are asking the server to execute the files and return the response. So the performance of the static pages `(.html)` should be better (even slightly in sometimes) .

**My suggestion :** If you don't need to run any server side script / DB communication / API consuming etc .. You may keep it as `.html` .

Comment: thanks for your input. It is a static site, so I think we should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

aspx pages may contain server side code / controls. If you do not have any server side code, them you can use HTML page in your SharePoint work.

Regards,
Purushottam